# The entire Ethercan API call being printed in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, ethereum, etherscan

I am trying to just get the "result" part of the API call response, but the entire call is being printed anyway.

```
final balance = await etherscan.tokenBalance(address: myAddress, contractAddress: getAddresses());

print(balance.result);
```

This is the response:

```
I/flutter ( 6425): api_url: https://api-rinkeby.etherscan.io
I/flutter ( 6425): query: {
I/flutter ( 6425):   "module": "account",
I/flutter ( 6425):   "action": "tokenbalance",
I/flutter ( 6425):   "apiKey": "*******",
I/flutter ( 6425):   "tag": "latest",
I/flutter ( 6425):   "contractaddress": "0x01BE23585060835E02B77ef475b0Cc51aA1e0709",
I/flutter ( 6425):   "address": "********"
I/flutter ( 6425): }
I/flutter ( 6425): response: {
I/flutter ( 6425):   "status": "1",
I/flutter ( 6425):   "message": "OK",
I/flutter ( 6425):   "result": "70000000000000000000"
I/flutter ( 6425): }
I/flutter ( 6425): 70000000000000000000
```

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The print looks like to be the last line of the log (where you just see the number) the other one looks like an internal log from the package, for any change did you used this package?

https://pub.dev/packages/etherscan_api

if yes did you initialized like you can see in the readme?

```
final eth = EtherscanAPI(
    apiKey: 'YourApiKey', // Api key
    chain: EthChain.ropsten, // Network/chain
    enableLogs: true // Enable Logging
  );
```

Maybe the `enableLogs: true` property is what is causing the logs to show, if this is the case please try to change it to false!

Comment: You are right! By default enableLogs is true, just had to switch it to false.